# less verbose ways of spec'ing records and maps?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Is there a less verbose way of making a spec for a map or a record than the way it is presented in the official spec guide?

```
(defrecord Person [first-name last-name email phone])
(s/def ::first-name string?)
(s/def ::last-name string?)
(s/def ::email ::email-type)
(s/def ::person (s/keys :req-un [::first-name ::last-name ::email]
                        :opt-un [::phone]))
```

ideally it would be nice if I could just write something like

```
(defrecord Person [first-name last-name email phone])
(s/def ::person (s/keys :req-un [:first-name string?
                                :last-name string?
                                :email ::email-type]
                        :opt-un [:phone]))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is Clojure team's conscious decision [to have values and key sets spec'ed separately](https://clojure.org/about/spec#_map_specs_should_be_of_keysets_only) (you can read [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11755028) discussion for a longer explanation). What you suggest is considered an anti-pattern in clojure.spec and was deliberately [made not possible](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/xwT9-H1YQBU).

If you want single-statement nested structure specs, it is probably better to use [Plumatic Schema](https://github.com/plumatic/schema).